# Django Select Query to get multiple columns with condition

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've a table/model 'ABC' that has two column fields 'A' and 'B'. I want to query the above table as follows:

```
select A, B from ABC where B is not null;
```

I'm able to do

```
select A, B from ABC;
```

but I don't know how to introduce the null check condition.
I've tried the following with no success:

```
ABC.objects.values('A', 'B')  # which is getting all the tuples including null valued 'B' column
ABC.objects.values('A', 'B', 'B__isnull=False')  # which is incorrect
ABC.objects.values('A', 'B__isnull=False')  # which is incorrect again.
```

Can someone provide the correct format/query which I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it :)

```
ABC.objects.values('A', 'B').exclude(B__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) method:

```
ABC.objects.filter(B__isnull=False).values('A', 'B')
```

As you mention it is also possible to use `exclude`:

```
ABC.objects.exclude(B__isnull=True).values('A', 'B')
```

The [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) method is the same as a filter, it just puts a `not` around the condition that is matched.  They're the perfect opposites, it's just the code will read better with filter in some circumstances, and exclude with other conditions.

There is [one minor note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values) in the docs about when the ordering of calls like `exclude` and `values`, but it doesn't make a logical difference:

> Finally, note that a ValuesQuerySet is a subclass of QuerySet and it implements most of the same methods. You can call filter() on it, order_by(), etc. That means that these two calls are identical:

```
Blog.objects.values().order_by('id')
Blog.objects.order_by('id').values()
```

> The people who made Django prefer to put all the SQL-affecting methods first, followed (optionally) by any output-affecting methods (such as values()), but it doesn’t really matter. This is your chance to really flaunt your individualism.

Comment: Actually I got the answer using "ABC.objects.values('A', 'B').exclude(B__isnull=True)". Could you tell me which approach is better and why?

Comment: `exclude` is basically a `filter` with NOT in front of it.